# Peut-on dire : « trancher le bien du mal » ?

Tags: expressions

Est-il correct de dire :

> Il a des principes qui lui permettent de trancher le bien *du* mal.

Si ce n’est pas correct, les seules alternatives que je trouve ne me plaisent pas.

Il y aurait « trancher *entre* le bien et le mal », « trancher *le* bien du mal » ou encore « des principes qui définissent précisément le bien et le mal », mais je trouve que je perds du sens.

Si la phrase du haut ne convient pas en connaissez vous une autre qui permettrait de souligner une attitude radicale, qui ne laisserait pas de place au doute : « il est sûr et certain que ça, c’est bien, ça, c’est mal ».

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Il a des principes qui lui permettent [de trancher le bien du mal](https://books.google.fr/books?id=eg0-CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT101&lpg=PT101&dq=%22trancher+le+bien+du+mal%22&source=bl&ots=OG1xN-bzeW&sig=qyRjcvOOFGLfFe9l2WXCT76Mh7g&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjY4J-elf7SAhUQsBQKHZIvCxAQ6AEIMDAE#v=onepage&q=%22trancher%20le%20bien%20du%20mal%22&f=false)* est tout à fait correct .

Cependant, [*trancher entre le bien et le mal*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=iJERKxd75vUC&pg=PT49&dq=%22trancher+entre+le+bien+et+le+mal%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGnty7lf7SAhXMwBQKHd9SC2AQ6AEIRDAH#v=onepage&q=%22trancher%20entre%20le%20bien%20et%20le%20mal%22&f=false) me paraît plus courant plus utilisé en français.

Tu peux ainsi utiliser celui que tu veux. À titre personnel, j'aurais tendance à utiliser la seconde, car je trouve que la notion de séparation est plus explicite en utilisant ***trancher entre***.

On aurait éventuellement pu utiliser :

- *séparer le bien du mal*
- *séparer le bien du mal*
- remplacer *bien/mal* par *bon/mauvais*

---

<sub>PS : L'usage de majuscules aux mots *Bien* et *Mal* peut avoir une connotation religieuse ou philosophique. Cela peut avoir une influence au sens que tu veux donner à ta phrase.</sub>

Comment: D'expérience personnelle et sans sous-entendre que ta réponse est incorrecte, linguee.fr est une source désastreuse.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps C'est noté, je vais éditer et modifier les liens vers ces expressions !

Comment: Pour préciser mon propos : j'ai souvent tapé des choses fausses et elles apparaissent dans *linguee*, car il répertorie simplement des sources diverses. D'ailleurs quand *linguee* est le premier lien qui ressort en tapant une expression dans Google, j'ai remarqué que c'était rarement bon signe. Mais attention à ne pas généraliser mon propos.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Je cherchais des exemples d'utilisation dans des livres. Du coup, j'ai édité mes liens vers Linguee pour pointer vers de véritables livres. Merci pour ton commentaire !

Comment: Un autre verbe que je rencontre souvent est _départager_ (le bien du mal), mais ce n'est sans doute pas assez prompt pour la question originale. Aussi, le lien vers _La dernière catastrophe_ ne semble me mener nulle part qui soit utile... Je manque quelque chose?

Comment: @Feelew Il devrait mener vers un texte sur Google Books avec [cette phrase surlignée](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uhii.png).

Comment: Cette image fonctionne. Le premier lien ne me mène qu'à la couverture et à une description du livre.

Answer (score 4):

**Les deux phrases sont grammaticalement correctes. Je propose qu'on retourne un peu vers le sens propre pour expérimenter et voir ce que ça donne:**

**Trancher le bien du mal.**

- *Trancher* est transitif. Le COD de *trancher* est sans doute *le bien*. *du mal* est donc un bel ablatif (le bien "qui vient du mal" avec idée de séparation). Ça colle grammaticalement mais le sens me gêne un peu à cause de l'oppposition traditionnelle exclusive du bien et du mal, question philosophique ou religieuse dont l'évocation n'est pas forcément le but de l'expression. C'est bien sûr une nuance vraiment ténue.
- Interprétation figurée : *trancher* utilisé au figuré dans le sens de distinguer ou séparer, donc construction allégorique "ad sensum" et ablatif correct. Ce serait au pire un solécisme.

**Trancher entre le bien et le mal.** Deux possibilités:

- Trancher comme verbe transitif dans son sens premier, et c'est toute l'expression qui est au figuré. On "coupe au milieu du bien et du mal".
- Trancher dans son sens moderne (le sens intuitif bien sûr) de prendre un parti parmi plusieurs possibilités, en l'occurence le bien et le mal. *Entre* est ici employé dans un sens plus étendu mais très ancien, c'est cohérent.

**Je préfère le deuxième, plus explicite, sans ambiguïté grammaticale.**

Comment: Ma préférence n'est pas aussi claire que la vôtre, et je ne ressens aucun malaise face à la tradition ou aux symboles religieux ou philosophiques, mon sentiment va donc un peu à l'inverse du vôtre, mais je plussoie allègrement en dépit de cela, car votre analyse grammaticale est claire, rigoureuse et intelligente.

Answer (score 4):

Je rejoins tout à fait Yves concernant l'ambiguïté de "trancher le bien du mal".

> Si la phrase du haut ne convient pas en connaissez vous une autre qui permettrait de souligner une attitude radicale, qui ne laisserait pas de place au doute : « il est sûr et certain que ça, c’est bien, ça, c’est mal ».

Voici ma suggestion : Pour souligner l'absence de doute, je suggérerais l'emploi de l'adverbe *indubitablement* accompagné d'un verbe marquant la séparation.

- Il a des principes qui lui permettent de distinguer indubitablement le bien du mal.
- Il a des principes qui lui permettent de séparer indubitablement le bien du mal.
- Il a des principes qui lui permettent de discerner indubitablement le bien du mal.